# I picked the wrong starter, is there any way to change it?

Tags: pokemon-go

At the beginning you have to choose a starter and I thought I would be able to catch all three of them. I caught a Charmander even though Squirtle is my favorite, is there any way to acquire a Squirtle or switch starters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Squirtles show up randomly in the wild.

Source: My buddy keeps bragging about it and sent me this picture[image]

Comment: I can also confirm: I have seen a bulbasaur in the wild. Alas, the app crashed when I went to battle it :-/

Comment: All the starters show up in the wild, however bulbasaur and squirtle seem more common.

Answer (score 1):

No Problem at all!
As mentioned you can catch all Starters in the wild.

Another way to get them is out of 2km eggs:
[image]

For the second part of the question:
Changing teams or starters is not supported at the moment, so choose carefully ;)